# How to backup iTunes on Windows to folder/share, i.e. without "Back Up to Disc"? No DVD writer available!

Tags: windows, backup, itunes, external-hard-drive, network-shares

*(Surprised I didn't already find an answer here to this!)*

I've got a computer on which I'd like to **back up the iTunes library** – music, movies, apps, *everything*.  We're talking multiple gigabytes.

Unfortunately, it seems that iTunes' own built-in *"Back Up to Disc"* feature (the only backup feature I can find in iTunes) only functions with a CD or DVD writer/burner.  The computer in question does **not** have a DVD burner.  While it has a CD burner, attempting to back up to CDs would require dozens of discs plus more time than I'm willing to spend swapping them.  So:

**What is the recommended way to back up an entire iTunes library on a Windows computer, to a non-CD/DVD location such as an external hard drive or a network shared folder?**

Then, once such a backup has been performed, what is the process for restoring the library – e.g. after the computer has been repaved with a new version of Windows – so that iTunes is resurrected whole and recognizes devices it syncs with?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried exporting your iTunes library? (and "import" for restoration.)  i expect that's the option you're looking for.  i don't use itunes so someone else will have to supply details.

Comment: Thanks - yes, I did try *Library...Export Library* and that yielded a single **Library.xml** file of 3.46 MB.  Looks like it is just an XML index that gets exported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a guide on how to do so from apple. http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1751

Comment: **Excellent link.**  Thank you.  I had originally only seen the other one about "Back Up to Disc".

Comment: I will, once I can confirm it worked for me.

Comment: **Confirmed it works.**  One tip:  Notice you need to press *SHIFT* when loading iTunes to have it prompt for a library location to load.